# JQuery val(" ") return null only in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Here is HTML code:

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
  <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
  <option value="WOMAN">WOMAN</option>
</select>
```

Here is Jquery:

```
$("#gender").val("");
```

IE shows nothing in the selected list(that's what I want). Firefox and Chrome shows "MAN"! What do I have to do as to oblige Firefox and Chrome let the selected list null?
Thank you

P.S. I do not want to add a blank option

Comment: You can do that, By default first option is selected value for dropdown.

Comment: This is not enough you have to give more js code. How you are trying? What event are you trying? etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can't select an option which doesn't exist (in your case, one with no value). You could prepend an empty option, and then set the value as empty:

```
$('#gender').prepend('<option />').val('');
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QFWyh/)

---

#### Edit

In response to your comment, you can just make the new option hidden:

```
$('#gender').prepend('<option style="display: none;">Choose</option>').val('');
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/QFWyh/10/)

Comment: I want a trick which does not present a third(blank) option inside the list. I just want two options and at the same time have the opportunity to display a null option which is not selectable by the user. IE does exactly that!!

Comment: Thank you for your idea. However, is it possible this third option to be e.g. "Choose" and at the the same time "Choose" won't appear as an option inside the list? I am trying to write val('Choose') but nothing happens...

Comment: Yes, you just need to set the `text`, not the `value`. Check my edit

Comment: Thanks again. However, how to set the text?I do not know. Could you write for me the right syntax?

Comment: **check my edit** - that puts the text directly into the string. If you want to set it separately you can use `.text('Choose')`

Comment: You 're right. However, I realised this is not a solution for me since I am using jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget (http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) and this rebuilds the list with all its options. Do you have any idea about this JQuery Widget? If yes, I'd appreciate your suggestion to achieve my goal. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$("#gender").val("");` will set the option with the empty value, which you don't have right now in your current HTML code.

Add an empty option like `<option value=""></option>` and it should work in all the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
  <option value=""></option>             <-- added a blank option
  <option value="MAN">MAN</option>
  <option value="WOMAN">WOMAN</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I do not want to add a blank option. I want only the two options.However, it works with IE. The problem is with Firefox and Chrome...

Comment: The problem is - chrome and FF will not let you set value of select that is not present - ..BTW - Why are you trying to set the value to blank ? and why you don't want to add blank option ?

Answer (score 0):

Like `$("#gender").val()` you can get the value

The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form element

not `.val("")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it on `pageload` and `onchange` event then you can append the `.change()` event at the end:

```
$(function(){ //<---------this is doc ready
  $('#gender').change(function(){
     alert($(this).val());
  }).change(); //<----this will triggerred on page load.
});
```